# How to display image in another activity after taking a picture?

Tags: java, android, image, camera, display

I want the photo I have taken and shown in another activity. I preferably would like to have a button for the next activity, when clicked, displays the image that I took. Just need a simple way. I'm new to android studio, therefore I'm not too sure how to solve this.

Here's my code

### Scanner.java

```
package mapp.com.sg.receiptscanner;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;



public class Scanner extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView imageView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scanner);

    Button btnCamera = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCamera);
    imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    btnCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent,0);
        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


}

public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Info.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
}
```

### activity_scanner.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingTop="16dp"
tools:context="mapp.com.sg.receiptscanner.Scanner">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="9"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#1f4991"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:text="Open Camera"
    android:id="@+id/btnCamera"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ProceedBtn"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/ProceedBtn" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ProceedBtn"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Proceed"
    android:background="#1f4991"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:onClick="onClick"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try converting your photo into byte and send it to another activity.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();

Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("photo", image);
startActivity(intent);
```

And get this in next activity and use decodeByteArray to create bitmap and set into the image view.

```
YourActivity.class

    byte[] byteArrayExtra = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("photo");

    //BitmapOptions is optional you can create bitmap without this also. This is the description of its use from google developer docs.
    //BitmapFactory.Options: null-ok; Options that control downsampling and whether the image should be completely decoded, or just is size returned.

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArrayExtra, 0, byteArrayExtra.length, new BitmapFactory.Options());

    //or
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArrayExtra, 0, byteArrayExtra.length);


    imageview.setimageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: Sry, I meant the first part of the code. The one that starts with ByteArrayOutputStream. Do i put this code in my onActivityResult method?